# Why is DOM doing this? (Wrong nodeName XML)

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this XML (just a little part.. the complete xml is big)

```
<Root>
  <Products>
    <Product ID="307488">
      <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="AR" Type="AgencyLink"/>
      <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="AM" Type="AgencyLink">
        <MetaData>
            <Value AttributeID="tipoDeCompra" ID="C">Compra Centralizada</Value>
        </MetaData>
      </ClassificationReference>
      </Product>
  </Products>
</Root>
```

Well... I want to get the data from the line

```
<Value AttributeID="tipoDeCompra" ID="C">Compra Centralizada</Value>
```

I'm using DOM and when I use **nodoValue.getTextContent()**  I got "Compra Centralizada" and that is ok...

But when I use **nodoValue.getNodeName()** I got "MetaData" but I was expecting "Value"

What is the explanations for this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code that initializes `nodoValue`

Comment: It would also be important to know how you created the documentBuilder (e.g. the attributes from the documentBuilderFactory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `nodeValue`variable most likely points to the `MetaData` node, so the returned name is correct.

Note that for an element node `Node.getTextContent()` returns the **concatenation** of the text content of all child nodes. Therefore in your example the text content of the `MetaData` element is equal to the text content of the `Value` element, namely `Compra Centralizada`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your are getting the Node object using getElementsByTagName("MetaData"). In this case nodoValue.getTextContent() will return the text content correctly but to get the node name you need to get the child node.

Answer (score 0):

Your current node must be MetaData and getTextContent() will give all the text within its opening and closing tags. This is because you are getting

> Compra Centralizada

as the value. You should get the first child using getChildNodes() and then can get the Value tag.